# Two Questions: How do I compute this Directional Derivative and interpret the given contour plot for critical points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gradient-flows

[image]

So I am completely lost right now and don't exactly know what my professor is asking me.

For Problem 3)

I figured if I am applying Directional Derivative twice on a function f, then:

$  D_u(D_uf) = f_x{_x} (cos^2\theta) + f_y{_y} (sin^2\theta) $

For problem 4, questions of this type has been the most difficult for me to understand. 
So here is how I tried to wrap my head around this problem and I am most likely completely wrong.
I just tried to imagine a tangent line for each plot and depending on the direction from the origin, I figured if the tangent line is negative, I can see in which direction it is decreasing altitude and therefore, determine a relative min or max.

For instance, we see that from 2 to 3, the tangent line is negative so there is a downward hill going from 2 to 3. Also, the altitude is decreasing from 3 to 4 even thought it is in the opposite direction of 2 so its like spiraling down?

I don't know. Someone please save me

EDIT:

Wait for problem 3 I think I figured it out just now:

Using the definition of Directional Derivatives:

Du(Duf) is Simply multiplying Du by Du and ultimately we get:

fxxcos^2o * fyy (sin^2o) - [fxy]^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$D_{\mathbf u}f=\mathbf u \bullet \nabla f=[3/5,4/5] \bullet [f_x,f_y]=3f_x/5+4f_y/5$$
$$D_{\mathbf u}(D_{\mathbf u}f)=[3/5,4/5] \bullet \nabla (3f_x/5+4f_y/5)$$
$$=[3/5,4/5] \bullet [3f_{xx}/5+4f_{yx}/5,3f_{xy}/5+4f_{yx}/5]$$ 
$$=9f_{xx}/25+12f_{yx}/25+12f_{xy}/25+16f_{yy}/25$$ 
$$=\begin{bmatrix}3/5&4/5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}f_{xx}&f_{xy}\\f_{yx}&f_{yy}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3/5\\4/5\end{bmatrix}$$
$$D_{[\cos \theta,\sin \theta]}(D_{[\cos \theta,\sin \theta]}f)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta&\sin \theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}f_{xx}&f_{xy}\\f_{yx}&f_{yy}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta\\\sin \theta\end{bmatrix}$$ In general, $$D_{\mathbf u}(D_{\mathbf u}f)=\mathbf u \text{ Hess(f) }\mathbf u^T.$$ Note that, by Clairaut's theorem the Hessian matrix is symmetric, so the quadratic form above is positive definite iff $f_{xx}>0$ and the determinant  $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}>0$

Comment: Ah.. yes I figured I should use the alternate definition of directional derivatives using gradient.. thank you